# Browse to find the JsonTextReader.cs

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I am trying to parse JSON using the NewtonSoft Schema and JSON dlls..  I am trying to open a file with my schema and will then hope to parse the JSON string I have but when trying to read the schema in I get the message 'browse to find the JsonTestReader.cs'..  Can someone advise?  Thank you so much.  ps, it errors on line 2.  Also I am using JSON dll version 6.0

```
    Using file__1 As StreamReader = File.OpenText("C:\VB Projects\ZooplaRTDF\ZooplaRTDF\JSONSchema.txt")
         Using reader As New JsonTextReader(file__1)
              Dim schema2 As JSchema = JSchema.Load(reader)
         End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: It means you have done something to cause an exception in the JSON method.  VS wants to help you debug the code

Comment: Admittedly this is a direct code translation by the telerik site from c# to vb so I haven't changed anything but the file path.  I did also try a different suggestion posed by them and I got the same message on a line similar to line 2.  I guess I may have the wrong reference loaded..

Comment: It could be a problem with the file